# how to correlate data strings from file in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I’m new on Spark and I’m trying to understand if it can fit my use case.

I have the following scenario. 
I have a file (it can be a log file, .txt, .csv, .xml or .json, I can 
produce the data in whatever format I prefer) with some data, e.g.: 
*Event “X”, City “Y”, Zone “Z”*

with different events, cities and zones. This data can be represented by 
string (like the one I wrote) in a .txt, or by XML , CSV, or JSON, as I 
wish. I can also send this data through TCP Socket, if I need it.

What I really want to do is to correlate each single entry with other 
similar entries by declaring rules. 
For example, I want to declare some rules on the data flow: if I received 
event X1 and event X2 in same city and same zone, I’ll want to do something 
(execute a .bat script, write a log file, etc). Same thing if I received the 
same string multiple times, or whatever rule I want to produce with these 
data strings. 
I’m trying to understand if Apache Spark can fit my use case. The only input 
data will be these strings from this file.

Can I correlate these events and how? Is there a GUI to do it?

Any hints and advices will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can:

```
spark.read.csv("your_file")
  .groupBy($"Y", $"Z")
  .agg(collect_list($"X").as("events"))
  .as[(String, String, Seq[String])]
  .filter(r => r._3.contains("X1") && r._3.contains("X2"))
  .foreach(r => {
    //do something with the relevant records
  })
```

There isn't really a GUI to speak of, unless you consider notebook type software a GUI, you'd be writing code either way.

Apache Spark is very powerful but has a bit of a learning curve. It's easy to start running in local mode for learning, but you won't have a performance benefit unless your data size requires you to scale to multiple nodes, and that comes with lots of admin overhead.

Comment: thank you for your answer. For now i will use locally.
How can I handle the fact that the .csv was countinously modified? I want to check it continously, because each N seconds there will be a new entry in the same file with the same form <Event “X”, City “Y”, Zone “Z”>, and i wish to check the correlation of data in near-real time.

Comment: For that you'd have to use a streaming solution. I'm not as familiar with [spark streaming](https://spark.apache.org/streaming/), but I believe it can work with similarly simple code. I know it used to operate on mini-batches, but I believe they've gotten even more granular than that. I'd only go this route if you expect to need to scale quickly to multiple nodes. Otherwise a local program to do the processing you need may be more efficient.